# Problema com o "sum" no RStudio

Tags: sum

Tenho um problema com a função `sum` no RStudio que retorna o erro que anexo. Sei que é um erro que não deveria ocorrer pois não é do código. Já reinstalei o RStudio e continua a dar o mesmo erro. Este erro não ocorre no R nem no RStudio de outro portátil. O que me aconselham a fazer? Existe alguma package que corrija isto?

`x <- sample( 6, 1000, replace = T)
sum ( x == 3)`

Erro

`Error in sum(x == 3) : argument "x" is missing, with no default`

Comment: pelo que li em outros lugares, isso pode ser por você ter duas funções com o nome sum, se você der um rm(sum) e tentar em seguida, o que acontece?

Comment: Caro Lucas Miranda. Obrigado pelo seu comentário. Ficou resolvido. Ainda tenho pouca experiência e não imaginava que fosse esse o problema.

Comment: Bom dia, taunus, que bom que resolveu! responda a própria pergunta então e marque como certa para futuramente caso alguém ter essa duvida saiba o que fazer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A questão foi resolvida com o apoio do Lucas Miranda e a solução consistia em limpar a memória do RStudio através do comando `rm(sum)`pois existia uma função com o nome de `sum`que estava a gerar conflito com a operação de somatório